# Delete rows out of 2D-array?

Tags: python, keras

I'm currently loading a CSV-table using command

```
xTrain= loadtxt('input_train.csv')
```

For testing purposes I do not want to use all of the data but would prefer to avoid to change the CSV file frequently.

So my question: how can I delete complete rows out of xTrain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a row from a 2D array in this manner:

```
from array import *
T = [[11, 12, 5, 2], [15, 6,10], [10, 8, 12, 5], [12,15,8,6]]

# delete the last row
del T[3]

for r in T:
    for c in r:
        print(c,end = " ")
    print()
```

The output:

```
11 12 5 2 
15 6 10 
10 8 12 5
```

If you are using numpy, then you can delete in this manner:

```
import numpy as np 

arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4) 
print("arr : \n", arr) 
print("Shape : ", arr.shape) 

# deletion from 2D array  
a = np.delete(arr, 1, 0) 
''' 
        [[ 0  1  2  3] 
         [ 4  5  6  7] -> deleted 
         [ 8  9 10 11]] 
'''
print("\nafter deletion: \n", a) 
print("Shape : ", a.shape)
```

Output:

```
arr : 
 [[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
Shape :  (3, 4)

after deletion:
 [[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
Shape :  (2, 4)
```

**Documentation**: Numpy.delete(arr, obj, axis)

1. obj: Can be a slice, an integer or array of integers, indicating the subarray to be deleted from the input array
2. axis: The axis along which to delete the given subarray. If not given, arr is flattened

Hope this helps. Good luck. Comment if you have any further questions.